# Android :How to avoid to perform action simultaneously on togglebutton

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am developing an application in which i am using number of [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html).on ON and OFF action i am performing different action. its home Automation based application so buttons are for AC,TV,Light etc. i have fixed byte array to ON and OFF this equipment. i am writing and reading this byte array using socket. but my problem is  when user presses two button simultaneously then the button status are gets blinked and sometimes its showing me a ANR dialogues.

Here is my code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if(v.equals(fanDimmer1))
    {
        if (fanDimmer1.isChecked()) {
        setByteArray((byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xff);
        } else {
        setByteArray((byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00);
       }
    }
    else if(v.equals(fanDimmer2))
    {
        if (fanDimmer2.isChecked()) {
        setByteArray((byte) 0x02, (byte) 0xff);
        } else {
        setByteArray((byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x00);
     }
    } 
}
```

And here is the SetByteArray() method.

```
private synchronized void setByteArray(final byte a, final byte b) 
    {
        new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                    byte[] data2 = new byte[1024], packet2 =
                        { 
                            (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,
                            (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x06,
                            (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x05,(byte) 0x00, 
                             a, b,(byte) 0x00 
                        };

                    //o.write(packet2);
                     write(packet2);
                    i.read(data2, 0, 1024);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start(); 
    }
```

**Update:**

here is the write() method

```
public synchronized  void write(byte[] pkg)
{
       try {
            o.write(pkg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

initializations:

```
s = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
i = s.getInputStream();
o = s.getOutputStream();
```

**Update2**
this is what i am doing in main thread to set status

```
Runnable m_statusChecker = new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        if (count == 0) {
            updateStatus();
            count = 1;
        } else {
            updateStatus1();
            count = 0;
        }
        m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker,Integer.parseInt(interval));
    }

    private synchronized void updateStatus() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
            { 
                (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, 
                (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x06, 
                (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00,
                (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x19
            };

            write(packet1);
            i.read(data1, 0, 1024);

            byte_to_hex = ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(18, 26);

            char[] arr = byte_to_hex.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) 
            {
                char temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            swapped_result=new String(arr);
            result = ConversionMethods.hexStringToNBitBinary(swapped_result, 32);

            int counter = 0;
            for( int i=0; i<result.length(); i++ ) 
            {
                if( result.charAt(i) == '1' )
                {
                    counter++;        
                }  
            }
            status=Integer.toString(counter);   
            runOnUiThread(updateButtons);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**updateButtons()**

```
Runnable updateButtons=new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        txt_status.setText(status);
        /*Log.v(TAG, "status is ::"+status);*/
        char[] c=result.toCharArray();
        int count=0;
        for (int i=0;i<24;i++)
        {
            count++;
            char j=c[i];
            Log.v(TAG, count+"::"+j);
            if(count==1)
                toggleButton=dimmerLight1;
            else if(count==2)
                toggleButton=dimmerLight2;
            else if(count==3)
                toggleButton=dimmerLight3;
            else if(count==4)
                toggleButton=dimmerLight4; 
            else if(count==5)
                toggleButton=dimmerLight5;
            ............
            ............

            if(j=='1')
                toggleButton.setChecked(true);
            else
                toggleButton.setChecked(false); 
        }

    }
};
```

How to deal with this situation. i have 24 this kind of [ToggleButtons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html). if anyone had this issue before then share with me.

Any help and idea will be appreciated.
 Thanks

Comment: How did you conclude you need to use `equals()` for comparisons of `v`? -- What is `i`, and why is `o` commented out? -- Are you aware that you're probably starting several Threads in parallel when the user presses buttons too quickly? What is happening to `data2`? -- The `synchronized` is not doing what I presume you think it does. ;)

Comment: disable the buttons while you are processing and enable it when you are done. Additionally you could always cancel the one which is executing and start another one.

Comment: @ClassStacker i have updated the question please check

Comment: Why are they blinking? And what do you do in mainThread that cause ANR? I do not see anything in given code that can cause it. Why do you create iD/oD, but read/write from/to i/o directly?

Comment: @Leonidos in main thread i am setting the status on|off for that toggle buttons in case if someone switched of fan then it should be shown OFF in application too. so i am checking this status every second setting status accordingly

Comment: @juned You're checking the status _every second_? Why wouldn't you just use a single point of information?

Comment: @ClassStacker to check the status of buttons i have another fixed 12 byte array, which i am writing to socket and in response i am getting the status of all buttons, and i am setting toggle `on|off` based on this result. what is the other way to do the same ?

Comment: Are you saying that you potentially modify the data "behind" the toggle buttons, asynchronously?

Comment: @ClassStacker yeah if you wish i can show you that implementation too.

Comment: Too much code, not enough concept. I'll provide a conceptual answer.

Comment: @ClassStacker it will be fine, even small guidance will be appreciable. please see my update2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single thread executor to sent your data sequentially. Do not create new thread for each data transfer.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private void setByteArray(final byte a, final byte b) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            // your code here
        } 
    });
}
```

All Runnables will be executed one by one.

Comment: so i should implement my `setByteArray()` method using executor right ?

Comment: updated answer. this should work if your write/read work synchronously.

Comment: Thanks, its improved the performance but yet issue is not solved !

Comment: can i use this this logic where i am setting button status using `Runnable` ? after implementing your idea it only blinks occasionally that's great for me

Comment: what do you mean by "blinking"? Toggle button can be ON or OF.

Comment: Earlier if i was pressing togglebutton too frequently then it gets blinked but now this is not the case. so now i am thinking to implement this logic with other `runnables`.

Comment: You can disable buttons, wait for responce from server and enable them. Or create some logic to handle this situations. You should know better how to deal with this in your app.

Comment: Actually my process is too frequent,i am checking those status values in every 200 ms.so its very difficult for me handle this situation,my layout is like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621106/android-how-do-i-create-this-type-of-layout).   anyway i will try it myself. thanks a lot for help

Comment: Goog luck. Accept my answer if you are happy )

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of understanding of what you intend to do, I suggest the following.

- Have a complete array of the values in your Activity.
- Make your click event handler modify the array of values and
- after that, start a new `AsyncTask` created on-the fly.
- In `onPreExecute` of that AsyncTask (executed on the main UI thread), disable all checkboxes.
- In `doInBackground` of the AsyncTask, send the values and receive them again.
- In `onPostExecute`, set the state of all checkboxes in accordance with the newly received data, and enable them afterwards.

If this is not responsive enough, you need to make a decision about how to handle setting conflicts. I think this depends on the nature of the setting. Either way, the scheme can easily extended:

- In `onPreExecute`, make a copy of the current values, but do not disable the checkboxes.
- In `doInBackground`, receive the values in another copy of the array.
- In `onPostExecute` (executed on the main UI thread), compare the received vlaues with the values for the checkboxes. If they are not equal, fire a new AsyncTask to send the values representing the user settings.

This implements a strategy for conflict solution which means that the user's settings are supposed to override the feedback. If another strategy is required, you may get the idea how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for answer i will try to implement this way